# What is task_instance.xcom_pull in AIrflow?

Tags: airflow, amazon-emr, airflow-2.x

I am trying to run EMR through Airflow and found example where it says

```
 step_adder = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='add_steps',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=SPARK_STEPS,
    )

    step_checker = EmrStepSensor(
        task_id='watch_step',
        job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
        step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='add_steps', key='return_value')[0] }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    )
```

what is job_flow_id ={{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}

what does this tell me?

Thanks,
Xi

Comment: Please check this. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/emr.html. Job flow defines the entire EMR process for your application. This defines how to create EMR,what Job you need to runs, if you want to terminate the cluster etc etc. Also care for IAM role while creating the same.

Comment: Also see this doc on xcom pulls and pushes

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Airflow tasks can not share data however they can share metadata. This is done by a task writing record to the Xcom table in the database while other task read it.

`task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value'))` means:

1. Go to the Xcom table
2. find the row matched to this DagRun and `task_id='create_job_flow'`
3. return the entry saved under `key='return_value'`

The `{{ }}` is syntax of Jinja engine that means "print" the value. This is needed since the value that you are seeking exist only during run time. In terms that `create_job_flow` task must run and save the value to the database before `add_steps` task can read the value.
In practice this means that the `create_job_flow` task is creating EMR instance and saving the instance/machine id to the Xcom table. The next task is `add_steps` which means that you want to submit steps to the machine - for that you need the machine id thus you must read (pull) the value from the Xcom table. The value will be different per DagRun as each DagRun creates a new machine.

Comment: What is the lifetime of `task_instance`? I understand how to use it but I don't fully comprehend from a python perspective where and when is the object created, because at no point you define a `task_instance = TaskInstance()` object. Could you clarify the lifecycle of that object? Many thanks!